# Add a document to the mongodb with pre-populated start and end of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a program in node js. I want to be able to insert a String into the dbs, however I want to set pre populated start and end of that string. This example will help me explain it better:

I have a schema:

```
var Cat = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  url: String
})
```

And when I add a cat document e.g.

```
var post = new Cat({name: "Emily", url: "test"})
```

It will save as 'name= Emily, url = test'

THE CHALLENGE:
I want it to save as this `'name= Emily, url = http://test/extension'`

So I want to pre populate any `url` added with `'http://'` at the start and `'/extension'` at the end.

I tried modifying the schema like this:

```
var Cat = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  url: 'http://' + String + '/nodes'
})
```

Which gives me an error

```
TypeError: Undefined type `Http://function String() { [native code] }/extension` at `url`
```

I add new documents from different places in my project, so I just want to find a way to pre-populate this from one place, rather than pre-populating it whilst adding new documents across the whole project.
Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
var Cat = new Schema({
        name: String,
        url: String
    });

if (!Cat.options.toJSON)
    Cat.options.toJSON = {};

Cat.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
    ret.populatedUrl = 'http://' + ret.url + '/extension';

    // you can also delete url key if you want
    delete ret.url;
};
```

Output:

```
{name: 'name', populatedUrl: 'http://{url}/extension'}
```

Comment: if you call object like catInstance.toJSON({foo:true,bar:2}), "options" parameter will represent that parameter. 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: I am afraid this does not work - I get the following error 'Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined'

Comment: I did in the question